# How to dynamically change number of columns in a ul

Tags: html, css

I have a ul with 2 columns, but what I would like to do is make it 3 columns if the browser gets widened past a certain size. (ex. I have a 23 inch monitor and want three columns if my screen is completely expanded) Can this be done in CSS or something else?

My css looks like this

```
.search-results {
padding: 10px 0 20px 20px;
border: 3px solid black;
height: 100%;
}

ul{
width:100%;
list-style-type: none;
height: 100%;
background-color: pink;
}

li{
background:green;
float:left;
height:250px;
margin:0 10px 10px 0;
width:45%;
}

li:nth-child(even){
margin-right:0;
}
```

here is the html

```
<div class="search-results">
        <ul>
            @foreach (var gift in Model)
            {
                <li>
                    @gift.Name
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to lose the column entirely or does the data contained within the third column have to merge with the data that's in the other two columns?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking. If I have two columns and I resizde the screen and make it wider I want some of the items from the <li> to move up into the 3rd column. This would prevent me from making the <li> to big, I want them to stay a certain size but not have any white space to the right of the <ul>. Check out www.airbnb.com results page, when you expand the results go from 2->3 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)?

It is pretty common strategy when you want to manage some responsive content.

**Normal screen:**

```
li {
    width:45%;
}
```

**Over 1200px wide screen:**

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    li {
        width:25%;
    }
}
```